# Is Enterprise GIS license required to use Production Mapping license?

Tags: arcmap, geoserver, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-production-mapping

I'm looking to build up a hybrid GIS Enterprise environment whereby multiple users can access data at the same time via Arcmap. If possible, we'd like to not have to spend a fortune doing this. My understanding is that I can edit data in GeoServer from ArcMap (with a Production Mapping license) via WFS-T. But through further research, it appears that I cannot get a production mapping license without first purchasing Enterprise. Is this correct?

Comment: The software that Esri created for just this is ArcSDE which was rolled into an ArcGIS for Server Enterprise license. As at 10.2 SDE has been EOLed, the latest help https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/connect-postgresql.htm mentions creating an PostGIS connection. This would meet your requirements on an intranet and the software is free; don't expect it to be easy to setup though, there are still a few steps that are hard to chase down from Google search, it would be best to contract an expert to install PostGIS to work with ArcGIS.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MichaelStimson.

Comment: Happy to help. I've not dove down into the direct connection to PostGIS myself, Esri sound fairly confident that direct connection will work as required without SDE. I have previously set up PostGIS for SDE and know how much of a task it is with not much in the way of help available for someone tackling unfamiliar software. Production mapping is a set of tools for editing and validation, in the demo I saw a few years ago the head user(s) could create jobs to assign to operators then had validation rules before letting the edits be reconciled, reporting back that the job is complete.

Comment: @MichaelStimson In your last sentence I think you're referring to the old Job Tracking eXtension (JTX) that became the Workflow Manager.  It was originally part of PLTS that became Production Mapping.  I only ever worked alongside people using PLTS and JTX, and did not use either personally so don't take my word on this without further investigation.

Comment: I'm in the same boat @PolyGeo, I have worked with people who used PLTS in ArcINFO and ArcGIS for Desktop; PLTS has evolved making it hard to remember which function belongs to each of the modules, the demo I saw was a few years ago. I think you're right, although Production Mapping can use workflows it's the Job Tracking and Data Reviewer https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-data-reviewer/overview that do the real work. It seems that production mapping looks to be focused on generating standardized maps, either digital or hard copy.These 3 extension are loosely bound together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question better posed direct to Esri (or one of its distributors) but from the [System Requirements for Esri Production Mapping](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/mapping-and-charting-solutions-system-requirements.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_845407658ACD4E6F8E3CD70922ED9B8C) it appears that the only **required** licensing (besides the Production Mapping extension license) is ArcGIS Desktop at either the Standard or Advanced license level.